# Настройка сети для KVM

Tags: kvm, сеть, linux

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь поднять виртуалку на kvm. Хост - Gentoo. Физический сетевой интерфейс всего один. Нужно настроить сеть так, чтоб и виртуалку, и хост было видно из локальной сети. Подскажите, куда смотреть.

Comment: @Freest, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поднять bridge, обычно это br0, на который перенести настройки сетевого адаптера.

Далее виртуальные машины в настройках используют интерфейс bridge (например, br0).

Bridge выполняет роль виртуального сетевого коммутатора (свитча), к которому будут подключены: внешний физический интерефейс с Вашей локальной сетью,  сетевой интерфейс хоста и сетевые интерфейсы гостевых виртуальных машин.

Как правильно настраивать Bridge в конкретном дистрибутиве, нужно смотреть документацию на этот дистрибутив - везде обвязка разная.

Однако можно поднять мост руками в любом дистрибутиве следующим образом:

1. Установить пакет bridge-utils
2. В консоле вручную сконфигурировать работу через Bridge:

   ```
    brctl addbr br0        # создаем интерефейс br0
    brctl stp br0 off      # выключаем поддержку Spaning Tree
    brctl addif br0 eth0   # привязываем физический интерефейс eth0 к мосту b0
    ifconfig br0  192.168.24.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 # переношу настройки  IP хоста на мост
    ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0  # удаляю настройки IP с физического интерфейса
   ```

Такую операцию лучше делать локально, в случае ошибок можно потерять связность.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если хост - десктоп или ноутбук и если на нем проводной или беспроводный интерфейс - это сетевая карта pci, то можно сделать на него маршрутизацию через virt-manager в свойствах подключения и включить в ядре поддержку proxy arp, как в этой статье

Настройка сети KVM в режиме bridge для Wi-Fi
/ Блог админа [Электронный ресурс] URL:
https://vankevich.ru/blog/nastrojka-seti-kvm-v-rezhime-bridge-dlja-wi-fi/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)